# Convert only matching keys from an array into object properties that match

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to convert only matching keys from an associative array into object properties that match them. The code I have below gives an error of `Unidentified variable : key` on this line `if(array_key_exists($array[$key], $classprop)){`.

```
<?php

class assoctoprop {

public $fname;
public $lname;
public $email;

public function assign(){
    $array = array("fname"=>"firstname", "lname"=>"lastname", "email"=>"my@email.com" );
    $classprop = get_object_vars($this);
    if(array_key_exists($array[$key], $classprop)){
          foreach($classprop as $key=>$value){
        $this->{$key} = $array[$key];
    }      
    }
}
}

$user = new assoctoprop;
$user->assign();

echo $user->fname."<br/>";
echo $user->lname."<br/>";
echo $user->email."<br/>";
?>
```

If I modify the method as such

```
   public function assign(){
    $array = array("fname"=>"firstname", "lname"=>"lastname", "email"=>"my@email.com" );
    foreach(get_object_vars($this) as $key=>$value){
        $this->{$key} = $array[$key];
    }
}
```

it works, but when one key do not match property or vice versa, an undefined index is shown.

Comment: @zerkms var_dump where?

Comment: *every* variable. Don't make assumptions on what variables contain, but make sure instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `if` statement inside the `foreach` loop because outside of it, `$key` is undefined. You also need to check for this `$key` in your array:

```
foreach($classprop as $key=>$value){
    if(array_key_exists($key, $array)){
```

You could of course also do it the other way around, loop over `$array` and check if the property exists in the object.

Answer (score 1):

```
   public function assign(){
    $array = array("fname"=>"firstname", "lname"=>"lastname", "email"=>"my@email.com" );
    foreach(get_object_vars($this) as $key=>$value){
        if(isset($array[$key])){
             $this->{$key} = $array[$key];
        } 
    }
}
```

please add if(isset($array[$key]) check

or better of you still need to init unmutched vars in an object

```
  public function assign(){
     $array = array("fname"=>"firstname", "lname"=>"lastname", "email"=>"my@email.com" );
     foreach(get_object_vars($this) as $key=>$value){
         $this->{$key} = isset($array[$key])? $array[$key] : "";

  }
}
```